# Execution takes too long when clipping vector with another vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, clip, overlapping-features

I have two vector layers:

- the red one is *'Landuse'*
- the orange is a vector extent of land below *'1mAHD'* extracted from a 5 meter DEM.

I want to clip out the 'Landuse' under the '1mAHD' layer. They  both have fairly complex geometry as you can see. The "Clip" is taking forever so I'm wondering if there's a Plugin, script or series of steps I could follow to complete this task faster and easier and without getting into doing things manually. i.e. editing all the small holes out!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution was a mix of many comments made on the question. The process used to perform the clip successfully was as follows.
The following processes were performed on the layer as 1 polygon.

Image A
[image: image_a]

- First, I used the ["Delete Holes"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes) feature with a threshold setting of 10,000,000. This effectively removed any internal holes in the polygons
- Second, I used the ["Smooth"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#smooth) tool to reduce the number of boundary vertices in the polygon.
- Third, I used the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool (as Q would not let me edit the whole layer as 1 polygon)
- Fourth, I had to manually edit all the small artifacts from the outsides of the clipping polygons to clean it up (Took a while !....). The resulting Polygon is shown in the second image.

Image B
[image: image_b]

- Once these tasks were performed the ["Clip"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) tool worked.The final output was the clipped landuse under 1mAHD. I was then able to calculate areas of each of the landuses under 1mAHD. Obviously there was a loss in accuracy due to the holes and external polygons being removed, but this was acceptable at the scale I was working with.

Image C
[image: image_c]

It seems that when the clipping overlay and underlying layers are highly detailed that the clipping tool does not work. Although it might on a smaller dataset. It would've been good to retain the detail and still perform the clip but the result was satisfactory nonetheless, with the steps detailed above.